# Showing Divergence of a complex sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a sequence $z_{n} = z^n+z^{2n}$ where $z$ is a complex number. How do I show that the sequence diverges when $|z| > 1$? I see that even in the cases where one cancels other, the magnitude of $z^2$ is always bigger than $z$, so there is no cancellation. So I know this sequence diverges. But how do I show that it does?

Comment: Have you tried "completing the square"? $\, x+x^2=(x+1/2)^2-1/4.$

Comment: @user1337 That's a very good answer in my opinion. Why don't you write it up?

Answer (score 0):

$$|z_n|\ge\left||z^{2n}|-|z^n|\right|=|z|^n(|z|^n-1)\Rightarrow |z_n|\to\infty$$